# Oracle get multiple rows from huge comma separated String (200000 characters)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What is the solution to get single column multiple rows from a large comma separated text.

```
Like
2015,PLANT,PEST,AND,DISEASE,CONTROL,PLANT,PEST

Should come as 
col1
-----
2015
PLANT
PEST
AND
DISEASE
CONTROL
PLANT
PEST
```

reg-ex solution which is available everywhere is not working with >4000 characters data

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify *what* doesn't work with regular expressions you used (and which one you used), but - for me, it works OK (don't have that long example, though, but - I'd suggest you to try it).

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '2015,PLANT,PEST,AND,DISEASE,CONTROL,PLANT,PEST' from dual union all
  3     select '2020,LITTLE,FOOT,WHAT,DOES,NOT,WORK' from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) col1
  6  from test cross join
  7       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
  9                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015
PLANT
PEST
AND
DISEASE
CONTROL
PLANT
PEST
2020
LITTLE
FOOT
WHAT
DOES
NOT
WORK

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```